# Filtering by exact list of IDs instead of "in_" list of IDs

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

`Item` has one-to-many relation with `Condition`. I need to query all the `Item`s that have *exactly* this list of `Conditions` (no subset, no superset).

Following query is obviously not good since found `Item.conditions` may be a subset of `item1.conditions`:

```
    condition_ids = [x.id for x in item1.conditions]
    DBSession.query(Item).join(Condition, Item.conditions).filter(
              Item.sku_id==item1.sku_id).filter(Condition.id.in_(condition_ids)).all()
```

Is is possible to achieve this sort of query result? (without "manual" elimination of all `Item`s afterwards that do not fit this condition of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
qry = DBSession.query(Item)

# ensure that each condition is present using separate condition
for cid in condition_ids:
    qry = qry.filter(Item.conditions.any(Condition.id == cid))

# ensure that other skills are not present:
qry = qry.filter(~Item.conditions.any(~Condition.id.in_(condition_ids)))
```

*This might not be the most efficient if you have many `condition_ids`, but it might be just good enough.*